How can I get the list in the body of the post request via query in the get request?
I have a post request in the project and I get a list in the body section. This service was requested to be converted to a get request and I need to get the list I get in the body as a query. The type of the list is a custom model. What is the best way to do this?
    [HttpPost(nameof(UserQuery))]
    public IActionResult UserQuery(ExampleModel query)
    {
        ...
        return Ok();
    }
    public class ExampleModel
    {
       public List<Example2Model>  Example2Models { get; set; }
    }
    public class Example2Model
    {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string SurName { get; set; }
       public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

I want to convert the old request like the one above into a get request. What is the most logical solution? What is the best way to do this since the query length will increase as the number of elements in the list increases?

Not enough information. Not by far. How is the data formatted? Do you have to deserialize it as XML, JSON, ProtoBuf, etc?

The json data in the body of the post request should be taken as a query in the get request. However, there is a list in the body of the post request, which is a custom model. The number of elements in this list may vary. How can I get this in get requests along with the query?

Still not enough information. If you can come up with a sample code for your Post request and its payload, perhaps someone will be able to provide a sample code for sending that payload in a Get request.

So is the JSON like {"Example2Models": [{"Name":"Programming","SurName":"Llama", "Phone Number":"01234567890"}] }?

Yes, but since it is a list, the number of elements may increase.

Yes, that's normally how lists work... I'm afraid I'm not really understanding the issue you're facing.

We will proceed by caching the get request. I need to get the body of the post request as a query in the get request. I am looking for the best way to do this with the list I gave as an example.

I came up with a way to get the request using compression algorithms. With algorithms like Deflate, Brotli. In this way, compressing and decompressing the data will be costly, but the URL will be shorter. Do you think it makes sense?
